# What type of images are required for voxel classification?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

In an algorithm, `voxel classification` approach is used to perform `image segmentation`. The aim was classifying voxels either as cartilage or background in MRI image. The project has to be completed in `matlab`.

MRI images has `.dcm` extension, it may have `.avi` and other types too, I am not sure.  **Is it possible to perform `voxel classification` on `.dcm` images or it require another type of images?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it doesn't matter what the format is, because you will load it as array/matrix anyway.

That being said, I never saw preprocessing being done on DICOM images, usually they are transformed to nifty or something else before anything is being done to it. However, ignorance is not an argument.

Comment: Do you mean, when operating on voxels, we operate on array/matrix created from an image? As I read about voxel, its related to 3d image, pixels are related to 2d image - which is `.dcm` in this case. Would you please give a simplest example about this?  Any pointer/link would be helpful.

Comment: well, if you are wroking on 2D images, you are working on 2D array of pixel intensities. It's the same with voxels, but you have 3D array,or 4D if you have also a time component. You cane xplore what is actually stored in those files -> 3D/4D matrix of voxel values http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html

Comment: You may also would like to answer my [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27843/18615).

Comment: Sorry I am just a user of tools other people developed, I don't know much about algorithms. But basic 2D image processing/computer vision is good place to start. The math is the same. Scikit-image hase nice examples on its website. For 3D things you might be looking for medical image processing. Also tools that are being used are often open source or at least the algorithm is published. For segmentation in MRI there is BET and FAST in FSL and also there are some other utilities being used from AFNII, SPM and freesurfer